# do something after second click?

Tags: jquery

Here is my dropdown menu code samples.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('.collapsedArchives ul li').click(function(){
            $('.collapsedArchives ul li ul').slideDown('slow');
       });
       $('.collapsedArchives ul li ul').click(function(){
            $('.collapsedArchives ul li ul li').slideDown('slow');
       });
    });
```

What should id do, using slideUp animation when user click slideDown's selectors click 2nd time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has [`.slideToggle( \[duration \] \[, complete \] )`](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$('.collapsedArchives ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Now you want to probably cancel the bubbling of the click also with [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('.collapsedArchives ul li').click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate option would be to store a variable in the object

```
$(item).data("somevar", true);
```

which you can check against, flip depending on the case and then have conditional which routes what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand the question clearly, but from the answers provided I guess you can use `this`, this will allow you to open/close the `li ul`  and leave the other elements on their current state `open` or `cloesed`

```
$('.collapsedArchives ul li').click(function () {
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

but I guess for a drop down you might want to close all other `il ul` which is other than the one you just clicked:

```
$('.collapsedArchives ul li').click(function () {
    $(".collapsedArchives ul li ul").slideUp('slow');
    $(this).find("ul").slideDown('slow');
});
```

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87Yke/1/)